# rsync over ssh "error in rsync protocol data stream" (code 12). ssh works

Tags: ssh, rsync

I tried:

```
rsync -v -v -e 'ssh -p YY' ./testfile me@XXXXX:/home
```

Error Message

```
opening connection using: ssh -p YY -l me 146.6.84.206 rsync ->-server -vvve.s . /home 
[sender] make_file(testfile,*,0)
send_file_list done
send_files starting
server_recv(2) starting pid=17537
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600)[sender=3.0.6]
_exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=600): about to call exit(12)
```

This works fine:

```
ssh -p YY me@XXXXX
```

Which suggests to me the problem is neither that `sshd` is not running nor that port YY is firewalled. I have checked anyway.

What other problems could there be?

EDIT:
The problem seems to have been "self resolving." I could not replicate the following day. I started my local computer up. Perhaps notably I had a different IP address than last time. And now rsync magically works. I'd appreciate guesses as to what it could have been in light of it going away.

Comment: Do you have write permission at `/home` of the remote server?

Comment: Sure. When I ssh I can start doing cat and touch etc.  On second thought I' not sure what you mean by remote. I'm talking about calling rsync while on a remote server to move things locally. I should have write permissions in both the original and destination folder

Comment: I've been getting this error (while trying to rsync my Pelican blog to my server) every once in a while. I find that if I ssh into the server, then try the rsync again, it works fine. Not sure what happens in between.

Comment: Not having enough space on the remote server can also raise this error.

Comment: You can also get a code 12 error if the rsync binary cant be found on the remote serve,r when rsyncing over ssh.  Try adding the path explcitly, using --rsync-path='/bin/rsync'

Comment: Note: 'rsync' command should be executable at both machine for remote sync!

Comment: In my case `rsync` was missing on the remote machine, so I just install it with `sudo apt install -y rsync`

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You can also get this error if you specify a remote path that doesn't exist.

I got this error on OS X:

```
$ rsync -avz public/ static:apps/myapp.com
building file list ... done
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Turned it was simply a matter of mistyping the destination path. The `apps` dir didn't exist. When I changed that to `static:sites/myapp.com` instead (the `sites` dir *did* exist), the error went away.

It's fine if the final directory in the path doesn't exist (I could do `static:sites/mynewapp.com`) but it appears any preceding directory must already exist.

Comment: I've almost forgotten asking this question. I haven't had the same problem since. I suspect that this is what happened.

Comment: also if you don't have rsync executable, it shows similar error. Mostly I have seen in ansibles

Comment: For some reason I thought rsync would create the directory if it didn't exist... I guess not - you need to create the destination directory first. If the destination path ends in a slash the directory must exist. If it does not end in a slash, the one level above it must exist.

Comment: I had permission related problem on my remove server...

Comment: Turns out on `archlinux` you need to have rsync on both the server and the client in order to make it work. If your server is under `archlinux` too, you can issue the following command: `pacman -S rsync`.

Comment: My problem is: remote disk is full.

Comment: You're right; I typed the dirname in uppercase

Comment: On my end it was, because I had to need a different port than 22. So also ssh command without -p 222 did not work. fixed this with parameter -e and providing the ssh command.

Answer (score 57):

I got this error when `rsync` wasn't installed on the target host. The error message in my case also said `rsync: command not found`. A simple

```
sudo apt-get install rsync
```

on the target host solved the problem.

Comment: I had the a code 12 error and no message about the rsync command not being found.  Once installed the error went away.

Comment: @abkrim, I've found this topic when I was searching Google for "Error in rsync protocol data stream". The reason was: after updating Debian from 9 to 10, rsync was gone in new system, so this exact answer really helped me. Missing rsync in target system may be a reason of similar errors — when rsync exits with code 12.

Comment: this is the first solution to try on a remote server! worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Does your login script at the remote end produce garbage on stdout?
Check this with

```
ssh -p YY me@XXXXX /bin/true > out.txt
```

If `out.txt` contains data, identify the offending statements in your `.profile` or `.bashrc` and wrap them in

```
if [ ! -t 1 ]; then
  echo garbage
fi
```

Comment: Nada in out.txt. But I also tried that this afternoon during a period where I could not reproduce problem.

Comment: I tried this at a time when I could produce the problem and I also got nothing in out.txt.

Answer (score 5):

This error can also happen if the path to rsync at the remote system is not what the local system assumes it to be.  You can see what is happening by specifying -vv (or even more vs).  If this is the problem you can specify the remote path to rsync with the  --rsync-path option.

Comment: Thank you, this did resolve my issue... now able to rsync to my synology box with `--rsync-path=/bin/rsync`

Comment: It worked! My Synology with the /usr/bin/rsync modified,  --rsync-path=/opt/bin/rsync solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks that what i was looking for ! :)

Comment: This! In my case it was a broken rsync in the default location (Synology NAS). When I specified the user one, everything worked!

Answer (score 3):

You may need to put in the full path to the ssh binary, ie

```
rsync -v -v -e '/usr/bin/ssh -p YY' ./testfile me@XXXXX:/home
```

Though there are other possible causes.

Comment: Yeah I read that could happen when you have multiple instances of ssh that you could be referencing. However, the fact that it went away the next day makes this unlikely

Answer (score 2):

I hit this error because I was rsyncing to a drive that was full! Check your disk usage if the other solutions here don't help you resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to run into this error for a specific file's transfer because a previously aborted rsync run seems to have corrupted the destination file (maybe due to interrupted delta/incremental changes on the destination file).

My solution was to find out which file caused the error (by using `-v` and/or `--progress`), deleting that file in the destination, then running rsync normally again.

Answer (score 2):

This happens if `ssh` is not "in line" with rsync. For instance, on GitHub actions, on a Windows runner, if one does `choco install rsync`, then `rsync` uses another ssh client. One needs to point `rsync` to `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\rsync\tools\bin`:

```
rsync ... -e 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\rsync\tools\bin\ssh.exe' ...
```

This resolves follwing error

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(231) [sender=3.2.7]
Error: Process completed with exit code 12.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this error:

```
rsync -e 'ssh -v'

debug1: Exit status 11
```

...

```
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-51/rsync/io.c(453)
[sender=2.6.9]
```

I was able to ssh into the remote host and found that it was out of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) for a pair of rsync's with different versions. So please check the rsync versions on both client and server.

In my case, local rsync was version 2.6.9 (on Mac OSX), while remote one was version 3 (can't remember now the exact version). Once I upgraded my local rsync to version 3 (using brew), the problem was fixed.